# How to add option to woo commerce edit order page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image]

How to add another option here like order actions, order totals. I know how to create option page but not how to edit woocommerce options . Is there any way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its really simple to customize the order and coupons in woocommerce because they are just another custom post type. You can use any functionality of a custom post type in there. You only need to keep in mind that the post type of `Orders` is `shop_order` and of `Coupons` is `shop_coupon`.

If you want to add some custom option inside the order editor page of woocommerce then use the following code to add a new meta box inside that post type.-

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes',function(){
    add_meta_box('custom_order_option', 'Custom Order Option', 'custom_order_option_cb','shop_order');
});
function custom_order_option_cb($post){
    // your code goes here...
}
```

For further details visit the codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/add_meta_box).

Comment: Nailed it +1. Also, there are *lots* of nice good working code for this at [wordpress.se].

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate, actually that project of mine is completed with plugin options :( but finally i found the solution. Not tested but seems good.