# how can i add a custom meta on edit order for image uploading. woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

i am doing a woocommerce site. My client want me a option ,so that he can add a image on every single order when he will edit the order, and user can view the image when they will login on my account page.
i have already try advance custom field plugin,but it doesn't work.

it give me output like

```
<img alt="" src="">
```

http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Answer (score 0):

[How to add option to woo commerce edit order page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409956/how-to-add-option-to-woo-commerce-edit-order-page/19607913#19607913)

in the meta box you need to add a way to upload an image, and get that image in the front end. That might be pretty simple.